# Facebook Like Button Dynamic Meta Tags (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, sdk, facebook-like

I'm trying to setup a Facebook like button within a modal and I'd like the OG meta to be specific to each image inside the modal. In my script I first add the required OG meta tags:

```
/* INSERT OPEN GRAPH META TAGS */
$('head').append('<meta property="og:title" content="'+x+'"/>
   <meta property="og:url" content="'+window.location.href+'"/>
   <meta property="og:description" content="'+z+'"/>
');
```

I've checked this and they're added just fine, at this point FB hasn't initialized or been called. Only certain modals have social icons, so when the modal is opened, the image loads and if social icons are needed it runs the following code and dynamically updates the OG meta tags based on some data-attributes for the element:

```
$('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content',currentImageParent.data('MetaTitle')); 

$('meta[property="og:description"]').attr('content',currentImageParent.data('MetaDescription'));
```

This works just fine and I can see the updates take place in the code. So after the image has been loaded in the modal, and the meta tags have been updated based on the image's .data info, I thought it would be safe to call the Facebook SDK to setup the like/send button (and add the required DIV to the page if it doesn't exist):

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root" class="FacebookSDK"></div>
   <script>
   function(d,s,id){
       var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if(d.getElementById(id))return;
       js=d.createElement(s); 
       js.id=id; 
       js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";     
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
   }(document,\'script\',\'facebook-jssdk\'));
   </script>
');
```

In the debugger this doesn't work, and just defaults to the non-OG meta tags (title/description). It also throws errors saying that og:url, etc are not defined (even though they've been added before calling it). If I place dummy OG meta tags on the html page and run the debugger I don't get any errors and the OG meta tag content (not the dynamically updated content, just the dummy content text) is display.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention that the url/links displayed in the FB debugger are identical in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's scraper does not execute the Javascript, and can therefore only read the meta-tags that are available in the HTML before any Javascript (or jQuery) execution.

You have to have a unique URL for each Open Graph object.